# Prove that the group $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to prove that $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is a cyclic group, where $p$ is a prime greater than 2. I want to show that there exists an element $a$ of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$ such that $o(a)=p-1$. Clearly, $n^{p-1}\equiv1$ mod $p$ for all $n$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$. But I don't know what to do next. Any hints (involving only group theory)?

Comment: See this: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/cyclicFp.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, there is a much more general statement: if $K$ is a field, then any finite subgroup $G \subseteq K^{\times}$ is cyclic.

My hint for proving this is to think about roots of certain polynomials. For example, think about what the order of an element in the multiplicative group means.

I hope this will get you started. I deliberately do not give a full solution because you ask for hints.

Comment: We haven't covered fields or polynomials yet. I think this exercise asks for an elementary solution involving only group theory! But thanks!

Comment: @LewisLi This is usually a fact proved in texts, not assigned as an exercise. If it were assigned as an exercise, there should be some kind of cyclicity-forcing lemma introduced beforehand. Anyway, if you don't have access to the multiplicative operation in the ring $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ then you can't even define $(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times$. What's your text?

Comment: Note: in the six different proofs in the notes that Prahlad links to, all of them at some point use some facts about polynomials. There might of course still exist an elementary proof, but I am not aware of any.

Comment: @anon We actually talked about multiplicative operation of rings at the beginning of the class. Then we continued with group theory. We are using a custom textbook by our professor. It is indeed strange that this is assigned as an exercise since all the solutions seem to use roots of polynomials, which the book has not covered yet.